# Возвращаются значения true, а должны строки имён пользователей

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++

Не удается получить список пользователей в Windows...

```
void FindUser() {
    comboBox1->Items->Clear();
    LPUSER_INFO_3 ui = NULL;
    DWORD dwRead = 0;
    DWORD dwTotal = 0;

    NetUserEnum(NULL, 3, FILTER_NORMAL_ACCOUNT,
                (LPBYTE * ) & ui, (DWORD) - 1, &dwRead,
                &dwTotal, NULL);

    for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwRead; i++) {
        comboBox1->Items->Add(Convert::ToString(ui->usri3_name));
        ui++;
    }
}
```

Возвращаются значения true, но должны строки - имен пользователей... Как исправить ситуацию? Прошу помощи...

Comment: Все работает прекрасно: возвращаются строки-имена пользователей, как и должны. А напортачено у вас в `Convert::ToString(ui->usri3_name)`. Что это такое вообще? Что такое `comboBox1`? Что такое `Convert::ToString`?

Comment: @AnT, мне необходимо каким-то образом вывести список пользователей на форму, в компонент comboBox или listBox... У меня не получается вообще никак увидеть этих пользователей! Вы не знаете как получить имя пользователя в формате String^ или string, чтобы дальше с ним работать?

Comment: `String^ name = gcnew String(ui->usri3_name);`

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, СПАСИБО! (какой же я пенёёёёёёёёк)